# Optimizing PHP connections

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have been recently overhauling a website I built for the company I work for. Because I started this project over a year ago, my coding skills have improved a lot and I want to bring the website up to speed. My main focuses for this project are security and speed. One thing I have been doing is changing all my PHP connections to make sure they are secure and fast. This is the format I generally follow when pulling stuff from a database:

```
<?php

    //Connect to MySQL
    require_once('includes/config.php');

    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Server connection failed. Please refresh the window. If this problem persits, please send an e-mail to <me>');
    }
    $db = mysql_select_db($database);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    $qry="SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE Category='<parameter>' ORDER BY substr(`P/N`,1,4) ASC";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "
    //Output code
";
    }
?>
```

Firstly, what is the best way to store connection variables, like MySQL username/password? In the above code, I am using a `require_once('includes/config.php')` which contains all my server variables. Is this a secure way to do it? Or is there a better way?

Secondly, should I be managing memory better? I was reading the PHP documentation and questions on this site about `mysql_close()` and I came to the conclusion I don’t really need it. However, lately I have been getting a fair amount failed connections.

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server

Is it possible this error is on my end with a bad coding technique? Or is it more likely to be with our hosting company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your logins and passwords out of the web root and include them with `require_once()`.

You can use `mysql_pconnect()` to use a persistent connection so future queries will just use the open connection instead of trying to re-connect. Ideally, you'd want to eliminate these connections as much as possible with a caching layer so the USER only ever hits cache, and your cache-writer only ever hits the db. Then you setup a cron or event-driven system to update the cache on a reasonable interval to control load per your application's needs.

Comment: Is this possible to do if we don't host the website ourselves?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not. I've done all those features for clients who host their own sites on Hostrocket and MediaTemple.

Comment: I'm not going to argue about the validity of my suggestion in a comment. If you don't understand the performance improvements, that's your problem - not mine and not the OP's. Take your attitude problem over to expertS-EXchange.

Answer (score 1):

A ton of people store their db connection like that and `require` it as needed. You could use an ORM layer like [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) to abstract the connection and so you don't have straight sql in your code.

about `mysql_close()` here's what the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php) says:

> mysql_close() closes the non-persistent connection to the MySQL server
>   that's associated with the specified link identifier.
>
> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open
>   links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

as Joel mentioned, you definitely should not have root executing queries on a web-facing app, make a user with only the privileges they need to access the db. Open root access anywhere is just asking to be hacked.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have the MySQL username and passwords off root, this way people can't access the files over the internet but PHP still can as they are on the local machine. This avoids things like messing up the PHP configuration making your passwords accessible.

Comment: Is this possible to do if we don't host the website ourselves?

Comment: Yes, If you use FTP Do you have a folder called public_html or htdocs or similar which files must be inside to be accessible over the internet?

Answer (score -3):

> Is this a secure way to do it?

yes

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server

that's problem with db server, not your application